# Mac App Store update issues after migrating to Retina MBP

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, permission, migration, accounts

I had a 2011 MBP and I just purchased the new RMBP. I used the startup migration assistant to port all my data, easy.

But I'm getting weird issues, when I opened programs for the first time I was prompted to put in my password.

Now, I am unable to update my apps (so far IMovie and IPhoto) through the mac app store, I get this error:[image]

I only have one account and I am logged in to that account.

I've followed the instructions regarding repairing disk permissions and re-indexing spotlight found [here](http://brettterpstra.com/quick-tip-fixing-the-other-account-mac-app-store-issue/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue when moving to my new iMac.  Unfortunately, I contacted Apple Support and even they could not solve the issue.

Eventually, they just gave me promo codes to purchase and re-download (for free) the iLife suite.

I would use [this Mac App Store support form](http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/contact.html?form=account&topic=Mac%20App%20Store%20Account%20and%20Billing) to contact them.

Comment: Ugh... Okay, ill call them. If it works out ill accept this

Comment: @MrJD Best of luck to you.  It took me a few days with back and forth emails to get my problem resolved, so hopefully they'll take care of your issue as well.